# Send only selected files and folders to Compress-Archive

Tags: powershell

Inside `c:\test\` I have:

- .\dir1
- .\dir2
- .\dir3

and

- file1.txt
- file2.txt
- file3.txt
- file4.txt

I want to compress only `dir1`, `dir2`, `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`

I use the following script to compress selected folders

```
$YourDirToCompress="C:\test\"
$ZipFileResult=".\result.zip"
$DirToInclude=@("dir1", "dir2")

Get-ChildItem $YourDirToCompress -Directory  | 
           where { $_.Name -in $DirToInclude} | 
              Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $ZipFileResult -Update
```

How would I be able to add my selected files (`file1.txt` & `file2.txt`) to final compressed `result.zip`?

Ideally I want the compression to happen in one go meaning I pass the list of selected files and folders and then do the compression.

Comment: you can find possible answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59018865/2349693

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $YourDirToCompress | Where {$_.Name -in $DirToInclude} | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $ZipfFileResult -Update
```

`Compress-Archrive` is capable of zipping both files and directories. So in this code we are using `Get-ChildItem` without the `-Directory` flag which will return all files and directories at the root-level of `$YourDirToCompress`

Then we pass those files/folders to the `Compress-Archive` cmdlet just as we did before.

*Assuming that the files are at the root level of `$YourDirToCompress`*

Answer (score 0):

If you compress a folder, all files and subfolders are also compressed.

So, what effort to compress specific files in a folder that you've already compressed?

Are you saying the files only live in `\dir3`?

If so, you just use a for loop and if statement. 
Match dir1 and dir2 then compress, then match file1 and file2 in dir3 then compress.